# Stopping a Control from handling routed events

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, event-handling, routed-events

Hopefully a simple question as I'm just getting to grips with routed events.

I have a custom `UserControl`. This contains lots of other controls.

Further up my tree I want to respond to double click events originating from one of the contained controls (not my `UserControl`). However, my `UserControl` is obviously catching the event and setting the `source` property to itself. How can I stop it doing this?

I cannot use `OriginalSource` since this points to the lowest level control clicked (`Border` or whatever).

eg.

```
MyWindow <--- Want to handle double click here with Source = MyContainedControl1
 |
 +-MyUserControl (this is setting Source to itself. How do I turn this off?)
    |
    +-MyContainedControl1 
       |
       Border    <---- Mouse double clicks here
       EditBox
       Etc
```

I have tried overriding `OnMouseDoubleClick()` and `OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick()` in `MyUserControl`, but at this point the events already have the Source set to `MyUserControl` even before calling base or anything.

Many thanks

Comment: perhaps you could write a custom event that is raised by MyContainedControl when a doubleclick event in a lower element is raised.

Then in your MyWindow the OriginalSource of  the custom element should be MyContainedControl1.

Comment: Add a method to MyUserControl that will takes an EventHandler as input.  Have the method then register the handler with MyContainedControl1-X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by changing my `UserControl` to a `ContentControl` instead. Luckily my content is all dynamically loaded at runtime, so I don't need the design time surface that `UserControl` provides. Despite much searching I couldn't find anything about the UserControl effects on events, other than one sentence within WPF Unleashed (page 722)

> That’s because UserControl differs very little from its ContentControl
>   base class; it has a different default control template, it has a
>   default content alignment of Stretch in both directions (rather than
>   Left and Top), it sets IsTabStop and Focusable to false by default,
>   **and it changes the source of any events raised from inner content to
>   be the UserControl itself**.

I also had to change to using `PreviewMouseDown` rather than `MouseDoubleClick`, since MouseDoubleClick is not a real bubbling event. See [Control.MouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx):

> Although this routed event seems to follow a bubbling route through an
>   element tree, it actually is a direct routed event that is raised
>   along the element tree by each UIElement.

If I had needed the `UserControl`, then I think I'd have had to do as Klaus78 suggests and raise my own custom event in ContainedControl, or subscribe to the double click events on each ContainedControl manually rather than letting them bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just walk the visual tree like so:

```
        private void Window_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = FindVisualParent<MyContainedControl1>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
            if (control != null)
            {
                //magic happens here
            }
        }

        public static T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            if (parent == null) 
                return null;
            T pT = parent as T;
            return pT != null ? pT : FindVisualParent<T>(parent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try changing your RoutingStrategy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routingstrategy.aspx

Comment: I do not raise the event. Control does.

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) API for this.